# Excel Formula Calculation - Display the aggregation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question on the excel sheet. Let's say I have 3 rows Status, Created, Updated

| Status | Created | Updated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| High | 12/08/2021 09:20:35 | 12/08/2021 09:25:35 |
| Highest | 12/08/2021 09:20:35 | 12/08/2021 09:45:35 |
| Low | 12/08/2021 09:20:35 | 12/08/2021 09:59:35 |
| High | 12/08/2021 09:20:35 | 12/08/2021 09:25:35 |
| Highest | 12/08/2021 09:20:35 | 12/08/2021 09:45:35 |
| Low | 12/08/2021 09:20:35 | 12/08/2021 09:59:35 |
| High | 12/08/2021 09:20:35 | 12/08/2021 09:25:35 |
| Highest | 12/08/2021 09:20:35 | 12/08/2021 09:45:35 |
| Low | 12/08/2021 09:20:35 | 12/08/2021 09:59:35 |
| High | 12/08/2021 09:20:35 | 12/08/2021 09:25:35 |
| Highest | 12/08/2021 09:20:35 | 12/08/2021 09:28:35 |
| Low | 12/08/2021 09:20:35 | 12/08/2021 09:59:35 |

So I want the formula which should display based on the below format

- For each row I need this execution
- If status is "Highest", then "Updated" - "Created" should not be greater than 10 mins. If it is greater than 10 mins we need to count it out.
- Final Result should be total count of the previous step

So, output should be

| Status | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Highest | 3 |

Thank you !!

Comment: Excel is not google sheets - please clear up the tags to only reflect the application you are using.

Comment: What solutions have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry for that tags confusion. I tried HLOOKUP but am not sure of using in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=SUM(IF(A:A="Highest", IF(C:C-B:B > TIME(0, 10, 0), 1, 0), 0))`

- Tested this one on a sheet where your 3 columns shown above were in columns A B and C, edit the formula to suit your exact references.
- Either this formula can't be in any of the above columns (e.g. directly below the table), or if you need it to be in one of the columns you should edit the range references to refer just to the source data e.g. change `A:A` to `A1:A13`
- it's an array formula so unless you're using Office365 2019 or newer, you need to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter once it's typed into the cell to apply it.